# Making link to Google Ads website open in new tab

Tags: html, hyperlink, google-ads-api

I would like to make link that open the Google Ads website in a new tab.

The link doesn't work in Chrome through. There seems to be some kind of block stopping the new tab from opening even though I have been told by Google that such a link would not violate their terms in any way.

Could anyone assist me in how to get the link to work please

```
<a href="https://ads.google.com/home" target="_blank">Link to Google Ads</a>
```

Comment: Working fine in Safari for me

Comment: If there is a block, then it is caused by either (a) other code on your page or (b) a browser extension you installed. Nothing about the code you shared will cause that.

Comment: its open in google chrome private window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ITs happen due to you enable browser ads stop extension. I pause that extension its works.

Remove or pause for that domain. it will work